# Action Cable --get all online Pub/Sub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

How to get all online consumers (publishers / subscribers)
who is currently streaming on specific channel ?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the number of subscribers in rails console with

```
ActionCable.server.connections.length
```

Also, if can see who is connected if you are using redis as the adapter.

Redis.new.pubsub("channels", "action_cable/*")
and to view the total number of connections.

```
Redis.new.pubsub("NUMPAT")
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I got empty packets when I run
Redis.new.pubsub("channels", "action_cable/*")


and I got  this error 
" ERR Unknown PUBSUB subcommand or wrong number of arguments for 'NUMPAT' "

when I run 
Redis.new.pubsub("NUMPAT", "action_cable/*")

Comment: @user3582703, are you sure you have active connections?. Also I've updated the numpat syntax.

Comment: where can I write this command ?
I want it to be written on a web page